# Can't run a ros package created with rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using rosjava from mercurial and ros electric from Ubuntu repository. I created a ros package following http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Build instructions. I try to execute it with:

```
$ rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py diarobot diarobot.scenario.diarobot.deploy.Deploy
```

but I get the following output:

```
Buildfile: /home/cassou/Documents/robotics/stacks/diarobot/dependencies.xml

get-dependencies:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
Executing command: ['java', '-classpath', u'/home/cassou/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.test_ros-0.0.0.jar:/home/cassou/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.roscpp-0.0.0.jar:/home/cassou/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.topic_tools-0.0.0.jar:/home/cassou/Documents/robotics/stacks/rosjava_bootstrap/apache_xmlrpc/target/org.ros.rosjava.apache-xmlrpc-3.1.3.jar:/home/cassou/Documents/robotics/stacks/rosjava_bootstrap/rosjava_bootstrap/target/org.ros.rosjava.rosjava_bootstrap-0.0.0.jar:/home/cassou/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.std_msgs-0.0.0.jar:/home/cassou/Documents/robotics/stacks/rosjava_bootstrap/rosjava/target/org.ros.rosjava-0.0.0.jar:/home/cassou/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.rosgraph_msgs-0.0.0.jar:/home/cassou/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.geometry_msgs-0.0.0.jar:/home/cassou/Documents/robotics/stacks/rosjava_bootstrap/apache_commons_util/target/org.ros.rosjava.ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar:/home/cassou/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.sensor_msgs-0.0.0.jar:/home/cassou/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/org.ros.rosjava.guava/r07/org.ros.rosjava.guava-r07.jar:/home/cassou/.m2/repository/dnsjava/org.ros.rosjava.dnsjava/2.1.1/org.ros.rosjava.dnsjava-2.1.1.jar:/home/cassou/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec/1.3.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec-1.3.0.jar:/home/cassou/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.jar:/home/cassou/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging/1.1.1/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/cassou/.m2/repository/org/jboss/netty/netty/3.2.4.Final/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar', 'org.ros.RosRun', 'diarobot.scenario.diarobot.deploy.Deploy']
Loading node class: diarobot.scenario.diarobot.deploy.Deploy
Unable to locate node: diarobot.scenario.diarobot.deploy.Deploy
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11160/can%27t-run-a-ros-package-created-with-rosjava/) by [Damien Cassou](https://answers.ros.org/users/1062/damien-cassou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like there may be a missing dependency in your manifest.xml or that your build.xml is not generating a jar for your package. You can debug this by looking at the classpath in the executed command. It should include the jar that has your class in it.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-10-11**:
I also had similar issue and `rosdep install rosjava_bootstrap` solved the problem

**Comment by [Damien Cassou](https://answers.ros.org/users/1062/damien-cassou/) on 2011-09-24**:
You are right, no jar were being constructed. Thank you